# Unit test FormSection component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-form, enzyme

Trying to unit test a redux-form `FormSection` component with enzyme shallow, and get the following error

`Error: FormSection must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`

What is the best option to avoid this error?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get around this error by mocking the `reduxForm` in the context as follows:

`shallow(<MyComponent {...props} />, { context:{ _reduxForm: {}}});`